# It comes later in the chapter, it comes in your chapter

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Is the use of "come in" natural in these sentences:

> It comes later in the chapter.

(That is, it happens a little further on in the chapter).

> This comes a little later in your chapter.

(Of a textbook, e.g., it has been discussed later in the chapter)

Is the use of "comes in" natural and common in this context? Is it used a lot?

Comment: It's perfectly idiomatic!

Comment: "your chapter" does not sound natural to me unless the subject wrote the chapter. "Your book" or "your reading" makes sense, but the chapter belongs to the book, not the reader. "This comes a little later in the/this chapter."

Comment: @d_b In a class context "your book" is often used for "the book you have been assigned tio read".

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is fine, but I don’t think your question is really about *come in*.

It’s worth noting that that *come in* is a [phrasal verb](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/come-in). Ships come in. The tide comes in. After a visitor rings your doorbell and you answer the door, you may invite them to come in.

Your question seems to be asking more about *come later* than *come in*.

That said, we do often use the preposition *in* after we use *come later*.

> The duel comes later in this scene.
>
> The part where the murderer gets caught comes later in the script.

However, if we don’t use a phrase like *later in the day* or *later in the chapter*, we can use *later on*:

> The proof of this comes later on.

Of course, you can always just use *later* on its own:

> The proof of this comes later.